# Retrieve Values from a Dictionary for a Bar Chart

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a dictionary that will be used by my barchart (and other graphs) instead of manually entering the x axis tick labels each time as shown: `query1.set_xticklabels(['Met Police','Thames Valley','Kent'],fontsize=12)`.

Something along the lines of this (although I am not sure how to implement it):

```py
dict = {'1': 'Met Police','3': 'Cumbria', '4': 'Lancashire', '43': 'Thames Valley', '46': 'Kent'}
```

This is my dataframe `df1`. The numbers in the police_force column correspond to different string-based values.

```
+---+--------------+---------+
|   | police_force |    ft   |
+---+--------------+---------+
| 0 |      1       |   129   |
| 1 |      43      |   59    |
| 2 |      46      |   56    |
+---+--------------+---------+
```

Here is my barchart:

```py
# uses seaborn library to generate graph

import seaborn as sns, pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline 
# to plot the graphs inline on jupyter notebook

# set style and size

sns.set(style='darkgrid',palette='rainbow',rc={'figure.figsize':(8,8)})

# read file

df1 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")

# define parameters for query1

query1 = sns.barplot(x=df1.police_force,y=df1.ft,data=df1)

query1.set_title('Polices forces with the most fatal accidents',fontsize=18)
query1.set_xlabel('Police Force',fontsize=14)
query1.set_ylabel('Fatalities',fontsize=12)
query1.set_xticklabels(['Met Police','Thames Valley','Kent'],fontsize=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first, don't name a variable `dict` as that is a keyword in Python. Let's assume you named it `pf_dict`, then the line you're asking about would become:

`query1.set_xticklabels([pf_dict[k] for k in df1.police_force], fontsize=12)`

But I would actually do it by adding the police force name to the DataFrame:

```
pf_dict = {
    '1': 'Met Police',
    '3': 'Cumbria',
    '4': 'Lancashire',
    '43': 'Thames Valley',
    '46': 'Kent'
}
df1['police_force_name'] = df1['police_force'].map(pf_dict)

# ...

query1.set_xticklabels(df1['police_force_name'], fontsize=12)
```

Comment: When I input and execute that code, my bars are each labelled 'nan'.